# Laravel XML sitemap, location, shared hosting

Tags: laravel, sitemap

I've uploaded a Laravel app, to a shared hosting provider (I know it's not the best, but it's for a local charity and everything needed to be free) The hosting is actually not bad, they allow SSH and I've managed to get Composer and Artisan running through PuTTY.

I followed the steps, for shared hosting uploading a Laravel app,, everything is running fine, so far.

I've been trying to upload a sitemap, to Google, but I keep getting a not found error. I've had the file in the root, the public_html and the folder that contains the logic, in my case wmcc.

None of these seem to work. I've generated my sitemap, in Screaming Frog, although I have used a couple of online ones, too. I've set my robots.txt file, I'm just out of ideas, where to place the xml file, if anybody can point me in the right direction, please? thanks

Comment: It needs to go in your `public` folder inside of the folder that contains your laravel project

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've tried that, previously. Obviously due to the differences in folder structure, the contents of public were placed in public_html and the rest of the project was placed into a new folder, called WMCC, which is at the same directory level as public_html. I thought that was the logical place to put it, I'll try again, but I definitely had the error.

Comment: Wherever you put your `index.php` that was in the `public` folder, is the same place your site map should go

Comment: Also, instead of hacking up your laravel project, you should create a symlink from the public folder location to the `public_html`. It keeps your repo intact just in case you decide to move elsewhere

Comment: I've actually got it working, now. Thanks, I tried it before and got an error, but I must have done something wrong, as it worked first time, this time. I'll have a little read up, on symlinks, although I understand what you are getting at and it would be easier than, hacking it up. Thanks, that's a great tip.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!